# Simple file encryption/decryption software for Windows?

Tags: windows, encryption

I'm looking for a software to encrypt and decrypt a file in Windows. It should be:

- simple (not too many features, should be able to just encrypt and decrypt it back)
- light-weight/portable (just few hundred KBs if possible)
- available as a single binary (executable file).

Comment: Please see [the meta question on how to ask questions here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/455/353)

Comment: I use AESCrypt (you right click on files and an option to encrypt/decrypt is in the context menu)

Comment: Try PowerArchiver 14.06.01. The problem is that its 18 MB. If you want to get further suggestions please edit your question properly.

Comment: I guess, the question follows the guideline now. Can you guys please care to upvote it now? :)

Comment: I did (almost half a year after you posted it). It is, indeed, a perfectly cromulent question now

Comment: @Mawg Thanks :) It would be great if at least two others did too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [gpg4usb](http://www.gpg4usb.org/):

- Not as small as a few kB but still only a 23 MB download
- Portable so you don't have to install to the machine in question just unzip and use.
- Runs on both Windows and Linux (Mac under development and in Alpha at the time of writing Sept 2014)
- Free (Libra & FLOSS)
- Public/Private Key based *i.e. the recipient does not have the key that was used to encrypt the file.*
- Compatible with GPG so for people who already have that installed, regardless of platform, they can receive and decrypt the file, (given the key).
- GUI based so easy to use.

[image: Screen Shot of Encrypting a file]